# How do I delete a WhatsApp group I'm a member of but not an admin?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm in a WhatsApp group and the topics discussed there are more of vulgarity. I need to delete that group. Please help.

Comment: If the question has been answered, please consider to mark a question as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

You can leave this group only, you can't delete it for everyone.

Go to the Group -> Group Info.

On the very bottom of the user list, you can see the button **Delete and exit group**

You will exit this group and the group will be deleted on your phone.

You won't recieve new messages (as you're no longer in the group) and the messages you already have will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

A group admin can remove you even if you don't have the app.

Answer (score -2):

Just go to what'sapp
Step 1:go to the group which u want to leave
Step 2:go to the bottom 
Step 4:you will see "Exit Group" 
Step 5:Click on that,and give ok
Step 6:now click on "Delete Group"
Step 7:and now you are no longer a participant in the group

Comment: This answer seems very similar to the [existing answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/68839/44325).